# MySQL Select non expired deals from one shop

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySQL database:

```
|deal_name|price|shop|expiration_date
 - - - - - -  -  - - -
|sale1|110|shop1|03-30-2012 00:00:00
|sale2|120|shop1|03-29-2012 00:00:00
|sale3|130|shop2|03-12-2012 00:00:00
|sale4|140|shop2|03-29-2012 00:00:00
|sale5|150|shop3|03-30-2012 12:00:00
|sale6|160|shop3|03-30-2012 00:00:00
```

On my homepage I want to show 1 deal from each shop ordered by the price and the deal cannot been expired.

Example homepage:
sale1
sale5

I have now this:

```
SELECT *
FROM deals
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(expiration_date,'%Y-%m-%d') >=CURDATE() $cat
ORDER BY deal_id ASC
```

How can I do it? What do I have to add? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about which deal you get then you can try adding MAX or MIN to the price  and then grouping

```
SELECT deal_name,MIN(price),shop
FROM deals
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(expiration_date,'%Y-%m-%d') >=CURDATE() $cat
GROUP BY deal_name,shop
ORDER BY deal_id ASC
```

Untested, but should get you started.

Comment: Doesn't work... I wanted also to select one deal from each store.

Comment: This doesn't return one deal for each store?